# iOS 11's Navigation Bar's RightBarButton greyed out when returning from a pushed ViewController

Tags: ios11, rightbarbuttonitem

I set a LeftBarButton "Cancel" and a RightBarButton "OK" this way

```
_barButtonOK = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(barButtonOKAction)];
[_barButtonOK setTintColor:BUTTON_TEXTCOLOR];
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItems:@[_barButtonOK]];

_barButtonCancel = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(barButtonCancelAction)];
[_barButtonCancel setTintColor:BUTTON_TEXTCOLOR];
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItems:@[_barButtonCancel]];
```

and they look like this

[image]

But when I push a ViewController and then pop it back, the OK button looks like being disabled (actually it is still enabled) like this

[image]

It is fine with iOS 10 but just grays out with iOS 11 and I don't know why. Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Having the exact same problem. If you tap on the "Ok" Button and drag a little it will become active, but no idea why this is happening. [link] (https://www.dropbox.com/s/pcasismzqcu6vpr/RightButtonProblem.mov?dl=0)

Comment: Having the exact same problem. Do you have a good workaround?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is gone after the upgrading of iOS/Xcode at some point of time. Definitely it was an iOS defect.